# Jquery with Bootstrap or Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question:

I have developed several site with Bootstrap but I am forced to work with V4 Foundation on a new project.

I read the documentation, it looks more easier side css but skinny side JS.

So my question is as follows:

Whether Foundation is full compatible with jQuery + jQuery UI plugins.
Because I did not want all my work again.

Did I do something in particular?

Thank you in advance.
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation on Foundataion V4](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

> Foundation JavaScript was designed to work with Zepto and jQuery right out of the gate.

Jquery UI should be okay as well but I have seen reports of bugs so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thx, I wanted to be sure;-) English is not my native language